# Distinguish recoverable exception vs un-recoverable exception?

Tags: java, exception

based on the definition of Oracle, one of different point between Checked exception and Runtime exception is “**recoverable capability**”. But, I don’t understand how to distinguish the difference between recoverable exception and un-recoverable exception. Some people told me:

- “**recoverable exception**” means it have a scenario(s) is defined (by programmer) when the exception happen. And, “recoverable exception” concerns the outside error (not the programming error).
- “**un-recoverable exception**” means you cannot do anything when the exception happen and the solution in this situation is just to fix the source code (re-write code). And, “un-recoverable exception” concerns the programming error (API error, method arguments error,…)
- But, “recoverable” concept does NOT mean that the application can do something to resolve the cause of the exception, even though there may be cases where this is possible.

but I don’t understand clearly the difference. So, I give the some scenarios as follows:

- 1st exception: Read from a non-existing file (**FileNotFoundException**)

***Read file X doesn’t exist on disk***

```
=>  This situation is recoverable or un-recoverable? Why?

=>  In this situation, if user choose the another file (through UI), it is the recoverable exception?
```

- 2nd exception: Divide a number to 0 (**ArithmeticException**)

***Divide a number by 0*** (e.g: 1/0)

```
=>  This situation is recoverable or un-recoverable? Why?

=>  In this situation, if user choose the another number <> 0 (through UI), it is the recoverable exception?
```

- 3rd exception: Call to a element that it doesn’t exist in array (**IndexOutOfBoundsException**)

***Array X has the length N, call X[-1] or X[N+1] is impossible***

```
=>  This situation is recoverable or un-recoverable? Why?

=>  In this situation, if user choose the another index (through UI), it is the recoverable exception?
```

- 4th exception: Call to null object (**NullPointerException**)

***Object X = null, referee to X (e.g function Y call to X,…)***

```
=>  This situation is recoverable or un-recoverable? Why?

=>  In this situation, if user choose the another object not null (through UI), it is the recoverable exception?
```

- 5th exception: Convert a invalid string to number (**NumberFormatException**)

***String X contains at least a not numeric character, convert X to numeric***

```
=>  This situation is recoverable or un-recoverable? Why?

=>  In this situation, if user choose the another string (through UI), it is the recoverable exception?
```

I don’t know why this exception is the runtime exception because I think when this exception occurs, the user just change the other string (may be through UI) to continue the program without re-write the code, e.g:

String X = “ba1” --> Integer Y (impossible)

change X = "123" --> Integer Y (possible), this action doesn't need to fix the code (???)

Example:

[Source code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vggo.jpg)

[Results example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43nPm.jpg)

Mostly the 5th scenario, I don't know why it is the runtime exception while the programmer can do nothing with the source code (rewrite code) <<<

Comment: Your examples are quite poor. They assume that the user has the capability to change almost anything through some UI. This is certainly not the case in `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and the like. In any case, there is no clear distinction and it depends a lot on your program's business logic. For example `FileNotFoundException` shouldn't happen with user chosen files, because you can check if the file exists beforehand. However if you're loading a file that **must** exist (e.g. config file for your program), then an unchecked exception is in order.

Comment: Thanks Kayaman, and how about the NumberFormatException, I don't understand why it's the un-recoverable exception? :))

Comment: It's not. It's an unchecked exception. All this "recoverable" thing is just philosophical thinking and pondering. There is no clear logic, and if you Google for a bit, you should be able to find *a lot* of discussions about the checked vs. unchecked controversy.

Comment: Oh, thanks...So "recoverable" or not depends on the thinking way of each person and purpose of this program...It's relatively, it's right? :))

Comment: Exactly. The only case where recoverability (or the lack of it) is clear, is with `Errors`. They always indicate a case where the programmer can't (or shouldn't try to) do anything.

Comment: 2 more question...While NumberFormatException is the programming error, why FileNotFound, mostly ParseException IS NOT programming error? And, "recoverability" as you said is the capability that it have a solution/scenario in order to the program can resume when the exception occurs (or fixing the bug - may be not possible), such as: change the other file (FileNotFoundException), close the error file (IOException), re-routing the request/message/.., when the server is down,???... Thanks for your answer :))

Comment: @Kayaman You are wrong about that it is possible to check file existence beforehand, unless you lock its parent directory. Another application may otherwise delete/create the file between your check, and  the actual open operation.